Azure SQL Database BEGIN TRANSACTION is not working
This is Azure SQL Database (Serverless).Simple statement:
BEGIN TRAN

DELETE FROM TestTransactions WHERE ID = 6
INSERT INTO TestTransactions (ID) VALUES (1)

COMMIT TRAN

INSERT statement fails due to primary key constraint, but the delete is not rolled back. What am I missing?
I tried various combinations of this code block, but it never works, I'm out of ideas...

The issue here is that the INSERT statement fails due to the primary key constraint violation, but without proper error handling, the transaction continues, and the DELETE is not rolled back. Fix: Use Explicit Error Handling with TRY...CATCH

As explained in comment, to ensure that the entire transaction is rolled back when an error occurs, you need to wrap your transaction within a TRY...CATCH block.
SQL Block
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    -- Delete an existing record
    DELETE FROM TestTransactions WHERE ID = 3;

    -- This will fail due to primary key violation
    INSERT INTO TestTransactions (ID) VALUES (1);

    -- Commit the transaction
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Rollback transaction on error
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    -- Rethrow the error
    THROW;
END CATCH;
GO

In SQL Server, if an error occurs inside a transaction, the transaction remains active unless explicitly rolled back. Without TRY...CATCH, SQL Server will continue processing even after an error. The TRY...CATCH structure ensures that when an error occurs (like a primary key violation), the transaction is properly rolled back, preventing partial data modification.
Example-


Once you are connected to your DB, insert some test data into the TestTransactions table for testing purpose

check that the data was inserted correctly, run

Now, you can proceed to test the transaction handling using the code which I shared above. Once you execute this, the transaction should handle the error (due to the primary key violation) and roll back any changes.

Next if you test the transaction handling, which will include both deleting a row and attempting to insert a duplicate (which will fail and trigger a rollback) you will observe that the script will do the following things-

Attempt to delete the row where ID = 3.
Try to insert a duplicate ID = 1, which will fail due to a primary key constraint violation.
Rollback the transaction, ensuring that the delete operation is also undone.

verify that the data in the TestTransactions table is unchanged-

See! all four rows, including ID = 3, are still present in the table confirms that the transaction was successfully rolled back. The DELETE operation was undone due to the primary key violation in the INSERT statement, and no changes were made to the data.
